# Getting High and Low of a barindex[Pine-Script]

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a barindexvalue(1002) stored in a int variable a. How to get high and low referring to int varible a?? I tried high[a] which is always getting 0 candle high? instead of high of 1002 bar?

Can some one help?

sample code:

```
indexarray=[1002,1004,1005,1010]

for i = 0 to (array.size(indexarray) == 0 ? na : array.size(indexarray) - 1)
    val := array.get(indexarray,i)
    highvalue:=high[val]
label.new(barindexval,high,str.tostring(val)+""+str.tostring(highvalue))
```

Comment: Please clarify your question and edit your code, some indentations are missing.

Comment: I made changes to the indentation...I want to know if there is methods that could return high and low by directly passing the barindex value if its stored as Int in a variable?@G.Lebret

Answer (score 0):

`high[a]` would return the `high` price of `a` bars ago.

If you know that that price is already in the past (`bar_index > a`), you can do `high[bar_index - a]`.

If you don't check for that and simply feed your condition from the array, you can check for `if (bar_index == a)`. This is because, your script will be executed on each bar so you need to wait until the bar count reaches to `a`.

Comment: +1 @vitruvius thanks for the reply. I got you..! But Just want to know if there any method that can high or low for a passed index value stored in a int variable directly?

Comment: There isn't any. As I said, if you know that that bar is in the past, you can do `high[bar_index - a]`. That's simple enough.